# Compilation error when building ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, babeljs, capacitor

I created an ionic app with the @ionic/cli from the terminal, with the capacitor implementation, but since before adding a platform, I must build the app I'm unable to do so. I get the following error

> An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] /Users/flameswitcher/Desktop/Projects/partners/partner-app/www/main-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/Users/flameswitcher/Desktop/Projects/partners/partner-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
>   See "/private/var/folders/c4/sgw5hxrx0mx16j941jv3xz8w0000gn/T/ng-lEsDYH/angular-errors.log" for further details.
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
>
> ng run app:build exited with exit code 127.

I wish I knew what's happening, I tried searching but couldn't find any answers, I also tried updating angular, ionic and Node.JS itself but didn't solve the issue, would appreciate some assistance with this as my projects are on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command and it will be solved.

```
npm i @babel/compact-data@7.8.0
```

Comment:  I was about to answer my question with the same answer, it does work, thanks for answering.

Comment: But has to be installed as a dev dependency using the option `--only=dev`

Comment: For me i only run this code and was solved and didn't need dev dependency